# Building different targets in different folders - Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have two targets in the same xcode project, as bundle plugins, and I want the executable files within the binary to have the same name for both targets.

Is there a way I can either:
A) Define the executable file for each binary without affecting the .bundle name (or first target overwrites the second target as they're building).
B) Build both files in their own folder.

They are in the same project, so the build end-results are automatically placed in the same folder. One overwrites the other, as the .bundle name always ends up the same (because I want the same executable name). They share a lot of code, so they are in the same project, to build everything again at once, to make sure everything always has the latest code across all versions.

Would anybody know a way of doing this? I tried various options in the build settings. Or would anybody maybe have any "build phase" workaround ideas? Please don't ignore that the executable name needs to be the same for all binaries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use targets with different names? Or a script after build, that copies the target to a different name?

This should copy each target to a unique name after build, without each build overwriting the other. (If things are linear)

Comment: Good idea actually, thanks. Though I'll test this in more dettail first, see what happens. If it doesn't work as hoped, I'll resort back to my original idea.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project for each slightly different built, with flags in the build settings for each target making each target distinct (with use of macros in the actual code).

Regarding in ensuring code is always the up-to-date, partially shared, code for each build/project, they share the source code by adding it to the project, without selecting the "copy to project folder" option. Annoying workaround, but it'll do until I work something better out...